# cho-han bakuchi

Tags: c

Estou tentando fazer em C o jogo *cho-han bakuchi*. Ele é bem simples, o jogo japonês consiste em lançar dois dados de 6 lados em um copo, antes dos dados serem mostrado o jogador faz a aposta dizendo *cho* (pares) ou *han* (impar). Então mostra os dados e os valores são somados.

O que estou errando no meu código?

Não gostaria do código completo, apenas do ponto em que estou errando para poder fazer a correção.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i,x,apost,cred=100,result=0;

    while(apost!=EOF)
    {
        printf("faça a aposta:(digite -1 para sair)\n");
        scanf("%d", &apost);

        cred=cred-apost;

        printf("escolha 1-cho(par) 2-han(impar):\n");
        scanf("%d", &x);

        switch(getc(x))
        {
            case 1:
                i=2+rand()%12;
                printf("\n%10d", i);

                if(i%2==0)
                {
                    printf("ganhou!\n");
                    cred=cred+(apost*2);
                }

                else
                    printf("perdeu!");

                break;

                case 2:
                    i=2+rand()%12;
                    printf("\n%10d", i);

                    if(i%2!=0)
                    {
                        printf("ganhou!\n");
                        cred=cred+(apost*2);
                    }

                    else
                    printf("perdeu!");
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Na edição você alterou o código no `case 1:`. Tem certeza de que é isso mesmo?

Comment: entao Guilherme eu estou aprendendo não tenho certeza estou fazendo tentativas e mantendo o codigo atualizado

Comment: Não mude o código da pergunta. Use o do momento que você teve a dúvida e o mantenha assim. Observe o [histórico de edições](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/23886/revisions) para saber direito o que mudou. A ideia é que a pergunta não perca contexto com a resposta para um futuro leitor.

Comment: ok mas bom eu vou deixar ele assim pois nao estou mais mechendo no codigo (por enquanto) eu sei q nao pode ser 2+rand()%12 e sim 1+rand()%6 duas vezes, como eu faço para somar isso eu posso por o resultado dentro de um aux?

Comment: `int i = 0;  i += 1+rand()%6;  i += 1+rand()%6;   printf("%d", i);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sempre compile usando warnings! Se você usa o GCC ou o Clang, passe essa opção: `-Wall` para habilitar todas as principais. Pode adicionar `-Wextra` para ter ainda mais alertas. Eles lhe pontariam alguns dos erros que vou listar:

1. **Variável não inicializada:**

   Você declarou a variável `int apost` e logo em seguida leu seu valor: `while(apost!=EOF)`. Ler o valor de uma variável sem antes dar um valor a ela é inválido, o seu executável pode fazer qualquer coisa. Na prática, essa condição pode dar verdadeira ou falsa de forma imprevisível. Sempre inicialize suas variáveis!
2. **Testar EOF em um `int`:**

   `apost` é um inteiro, armazena o valor da aposta. `scanf("%d", &apost);` lê um número. Por outro lado `EOF` é um `char` que indica fim da leitura e nunca vai ser retornado pelo scanf se você pediu a ele um número. Considere usar a seguinte lógica:

   ```
   while (true) {
       int apost;

       printf("faça a aposta:(digite -1 para sair)\n");
       scanf("%d", &apost);

       if (apost < 0) break;

       /* ... */
   }
   ```
3. **`getc` retorna uma letra, não um número:**

   Entenda que `'3'` **não** é a mesma coisa que `3`. O primeiro é uma letra, que equivale ao inteiro 53 na maioria dos sistemas (se usam ASCII). Você deve testar pelas letras no seu switch, assim: `case '1':`.
4. **Distribuição de probabilidade:**

   A soma de dois números aleatórios de 1 a 6 é **diferente** de um número aleatório de 2 a 12. Isso ocorre por que combinações que resultam em 5, por exemplo são muito mais prováveis que combinações que resultam em 2. Para formar 5 podemos ter: 1+4, 2+3, 3+2, 4+1. Enquanto que 2 pode ser apenas 1+1. Sendo assim ele será 4 vezes mais provável. Isso é a chamada distribuição normal. A correção, no entanto, é simples: gere os dois valores separadamente e depois some.

Comment: guilherme voce mesmo edito o meu while na hora que você fez a edição olha dinovo o meu codigo

Comment: eu tinha feito dessa forma da dica quatro na primeira vez e mesmo assim não tinha dado certo esta dando o mesmo erro o programa para de responder como se eu tivese esquecido de por o & no scanf

Comment: guilherme desculpa eu vi alguns erros que cometi inclusive o while foi mal

Comment: Hmmm: `EOF` é um valor de tipo `int`

Comment: @pmg, sim, é uma macro que se traduz em um inteiro. Mas representa o fim da entrada, e não foi usada nesse contexto.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal eu vo mudar o codigo eu modifiquei bastante o codigo mas to tendo um erro com a função enum se voce puder me ajudar eu ja concegui o jogo rodar mas ele tava bugando ai tentei arrumar pegando umas dicas do livro C como programar dos Ir. Deitel. Se você puder dar uma olhada.

Comment: @LeonardoV.DeGasperin Vou reverter sua edição. Para outra dúvida abra outra pergunta. Não reuse uma e descaracterize respostas já dadas.